# Weird ASP.NET MVC links with (A(anythingworkshere))

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Google's webmaster tools has started showing some very strange internal links for my site. It appears "normal", but I'm not sure what to make of it. If you use parentheses and put in a single letter, then put literally anything in parentheses after that, the link works. I did a search for any other MVC sites so I could see if they had the same behavior. Microsoft's site came up at the top of the list with an odd link as well. The search terms were "asp.net mvc site" and the first link I got was for:

http://www.asp.net/(S(d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45))/mvc

I don't like this at all. You can change the S to an A or any other letter, and then put any text you want in the next section. Anyone know how to stop it? For the life of me I can't see anything wrong with my routes. I used MVC so I wouldn't have strange url's floating around in search engines so this is pretty disappointing.

Nearest I can guess from the Google "internal links" list is that it may be a cookie. But I can't find any circumstance when I view the source on my site where I see anything but the proper relative links.

Comment: That looks weird. I am sure you already checked, but if there's one thing with your code you can check, it's to confirm that you haven't swapped the routeValues and the htmlProperties parameters in linkgeneration.

Comment: I'll check again, but I still haven't been able to get my sites to generate a link like this. If Google hadn't recorded them I never would have known this was even possible. I'm not sure if being able to put random data into a link for www.asp.net makes me feel better, or worries me even more...

Comment: I've tested many more sites identified as ASP.NET MVC and injecting http://www.somehost.com/(A(whatever-text-you-want))/validlink into the URL works on all of them.

Comment: Is stackoverflow asp.net MVC? I tried it here for the heck of it and it worked for this post:

http://stackoverflow.com/(A(test))/questions/3134933/wierd-asp-net-mvc-links-with-aanythingworkshere

Comment: Do you ue sesions on the website? @Ron Grove yes it is built on ASP.Net MVC

Comment: I cant re-create this on a default website so can you show us your routes?

Comment: The letter is also case sensitive.  http://www.asp.net/(B(d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45))/mvc works but http://www.asp.net/(b(d35rmemuuono1wvm1gsp2n45))/mvc returns a 404...hrm.  I have noticed this before, but thought it was a MS site issue, not a possible MVC issue.

Comment: ...and I was able to get this to occur on a MVC 2 site of my own.  Default route and one area, nothing fancy beyond that.

Comment: Yes, I do use sessions but mostly so I can login and create articles. I don't expect visitors to do so, though they could sign up for an account it doesn't get them anything at this time. Not sure what you're looking for in a route since it works for the whole site. There are too many to list here. Here's an example:

routes.MapRoute(
  "",
  "Article/Index/{category}/page{page}", 
  new { controller = "Article", action = "Index", category = (string)null, page = (int?)null },
  new { category = "[a-zA-Z0-9\\-]+", page = "[0-9]+" }
);

Comment: @Pino - I can recreate it with a brand new C# MVC 2.0 application that I don't touch in VS2010. This worked on the site: http://localhost:50165/(A(sometext))/Home/About

Just noticed it also remembers this for every page from then on. Just shoot me now... The only recent real change to my sites has been to update them to MVC 2. I don't remember having to do much, it "just worked" pretty well. I never saw these wierd urls with MVC 1. Can someone check an MVC 1 website?

Comment: @Ron Grove - same behavior in an MVC1 site.

Comment: I can confirm I can reproduce the freakshow on my live asp.net mvc 1.0 site too. And those views haven't been changed in o' so long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like the Session ID format used when cookieless sessions are turned on (`<sessionState cookieless="true" />` in Web.config). This appears to be general ASP.NET behavior, not just MVC, as I was able to reproduce this behavior with a standard 3.5 Website project in VS 2010.

It seems that ASP.NET will process values in that form as if it were a Session ID, even if you do not have cookieless sessions turned on.

It's hard to diagnose the situation without seeing your actual site configuration and logs, but if I had to guess, I'd say that the Google webmaster tools are not returning the session cookie to your site in the request, so the site is falling back to cookieless method in an attempt to maintain the session.

Comment: Someone in the www.asp.net web forum suggested cookieless session as well, but I don't think that's this problem. If I craft a URL that simply uses host.com/(session-variable)/valid-link it doesn't work. I have to have this wierd (A(test-text)) thing where the first section only contains one letter. If I make it (AA(test-text) it fails. I've added <sessionState cookieless="false" /> to the Web.config now (I didn't have an entry previously) and the behavior is the same.

Comment: Well, I should say manually injecting the text still works the same. I've never been able to replicate how Google got those urls so you could be right, I really don't know. If it's the cookieless="false" thing then it would be nice if that fixes it. Right now I'm still concerned that (A(test-text)) still works on every MVC site I've tried it on. :-(

Comment: The `host.com/(session-id)/x` is the .NET 1.1 format. Starting in 2.0, it switched to the `host.com/(S(session-id))/x` format. It appears that any uppercase character could be substituted for the "S". ASP.NET appears to always handle URLs in that format as cookieless session ids, even if you're not intending to use them. You can reproduce the behavior on any ASP.NET 2.0+ site, from what I've been able to determine.

Comment: In other words, it is a bit annoying that it confuses the logs and analysis tools, but it's normal behavior for an ASP.NET site, and there doesn't seem to be any way to prevent it, so I wouldn't worry too much about it.

Comment: I chose MVC because it's an article site. I wanted to guarantee the URL provided to the consumer (whether it's a bot or a person) would be exactly what I wanted. If I can't guarantee that with ASP.NET MVC then that's a serious, serious problem IMHO. I never specifically enabled cookieless sessionState in the first place, so specifying it as false should only be confirming the what I read should have been the default value. I'm ticked. I've spent all day, and I still don't know how google got those links and the all the work put into routing is down the drain if I can't guarantee outbound URLs.

Answer (score 1):

This is for cookieless sessions.

Since google is scanning with a bot, its using the cookieless session.

More info:

[Asp.net cookieless sessionId url location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595728/asp-net-cookieless-sessionid-url-location)