# Why does ASP.NET uses cookieless forms authentication in one given user's browser

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session-cookies

A tester of my new app reported problems with authorization support in ASP.NET MVC app: Whenever he switches to a new tab (different controller), he's prompted for his login again.

After investigation, I found that the server forcibly wants to use cookieless forms authentication using URLs such as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/595728/asp-net-cookieless-sessionid-url-location).

The problem appears in his Firefox 3.6.15. Not on other browsers on his computer, not on Firefox on other computers. I checked his Firefox options: Cookies are enabled. HTTPfox even says there is an ASPNetSessionId exchanged!

How come? Can anyone shed some light? FWIW, my web.config doesn't say anyhting about cookies or sessions. I didn't even know of these cookieless URLs before seeing them on this computer and doing some research.

Comment: Does it happen on any other website that he uses?  Is he asked to log in repeatedly on other sites?

Comment: Kaius, no, he says he never noticed any problem. I just noticed that when I wanted to install HttpFox (Firefox add-on), the Mozilla site, said "Please install Firefox". How come the *Mozilla* site doesn't even recognize the browser. Would there be something weird in his user agent string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstall and reinstall Firefox from his machine. backup his bookmarks first so he doesnt lose anything.  It sounds like its an installation issue rather than a coding problem.

Comment: @Serge - appTranslator  This question takes me back to my Tech Support days. All sorts of weird crap would happen for no reason. Quickest solution 90% of the time was uninstall and reinstall.    
Me: Did you turn it off and on again?  
Them: Yes  
Me: Click Start > Settings > Control Panel > Add Remove Prog...  

Job from hell.